# How to run a programme from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, shellexecute

```
mysql > path_to_bin/name.exe
```

Is there a solution?

Comment: The 'mysql > path_to_bin/name.exe' suggests you want to overwrite a (binary) file with the text output from mysql, which doesn't make sense.  The following text 'Is there a solution' is pretty vague.  If you are that imprecise, it would probably not be useful to go into a discussion of UDFs.

Comment: I need a solution pretty much like JohnK813's,but should also work with windows platform.

Answer (score 3):

No, that would be a huge security risk.

Comment: select * from puppies - "Are you sure you want to delete all files on your computer?"

Comment: There are other ways to solve something similar, if you really need to run programs, use a scheduler or something, but execution directly from sql? Let's just hope that's a "feature" that will never be done.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **\!** on the Linux side to execute simple shell commands, but

1. I can't say for certain that this
   will work on the Windows side, and
2. I agree with Filip's answer that there
   are inherent risks in doing this.

[Source](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/shell-commands-mysql-command-line-client/)

Comment: Because Windows and Linux is not the same operating system.